# How to call the function with exports defined outside describe() inside the describe() in same js file

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am trying to write something like

```
describe('Create User', function () {
  it('1: All Data Valid', function (done) {
    servicesGenerator.postPlayoApi(apiEndPoints.createUser)
    .send(this.getValidUserCreateBody())
    .end(function (err, res) {
      validator.userDataTypeValidator(err, res);
      done();
    });
  });
});

exports.getValidUserCreateBody = function() {
  return {
    "emailId": testData.emailIdDefault,
    "fName": testData.fNameDefault,
    "lName": testData.lNameDefault,
    "gender": testData.genderDefault,   
  };
}
```

But its giving error **TypeError: this.getValidUserCreateBody is not a function**
How should I proceed to implement this flow?

Comment: always use "use strict" to quickly locate the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hoisting](https://rainsoft.io/javascript-hoisting-in-details) got you. Please define `getValidUserCreateBody` above the describe.

Also, `this` in a function is different that `this` outside. Try using `getValidUserCreateBody` via closure.

```
var getValidUserCreateBody = function() {
  return {
    "emailId": testData.emailIdDefault,
    "fName": testData.fNameDefault,
    "lName": testData.lNameDefault,
    "gender": testData.genderDefault,   
  };
}

exports.getValidUserCreateBody = getValidUserCreateBody; //You don't necessarily need this line if you don't use it outside this file.

describe('Create User', function () {
  it('1: All Data Valid', function (done) {
    servicesGenerator.postPlayoApi(apiEndPoints.createUser)
    .send(getValidUserCreateBody())
    .end(function (err, res) {
      validator.userDataTypeValidator(err, res);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```